# How to cache Gradle dependencies inside Gitlab CI

Tags: android, gradle, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I add cache property inside my `gitlab-ci.yml` file in my Android project.

```
cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches
```

But in each pipeline when I run `./gradlew assemble`, It downloads all gradle dependencies which cause slow build time.

Answer (score 30):

I'm doing it like this

```
before_script:
  - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle

cache:
  paths:
    - .gradle/wrapper
    - .gradle/caches
```